# SnackBar style changed after using material components

Tags: kotlin, styles, material-components-android

Because I wanted to use material input edit text, I had to change my style to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge">
```

But my SnackBar style has changed, before it (which I was using AppCompat) my SnackBar was show in different mode, I mean, It came up from bottom and after a while it goes down, but now it is shown like a simple toast, it fade-in and then fade-out,
how can I use material component without having any change in my view styles?

Comment: Post the screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Add following lines into styles.xml BaseTheme:

```
<resources>
    <style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge">
        ...
        <item name="snackbarStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar</item>
        <item name="snackbarButtonStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Snackbar</item>
        <item name="snackbarTextViewStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar.TextView</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```